# High temperature and battery problems after update to Catalina

Tags: battery, performance

I wanted to do my friend a favour and updated her Macbook Air (2015) from El Capitan (10.11) to Catalina (10.15). She never bothered updating and despite having no apparent problems, I advised for the update mainly for security reasons.
After the installation, however, some performance issues have arisen: The temperature of the Macbook quickly rises even when performing minor operations such as browsing images with Finder. The battery drains much more quickly than before. At first I suspected Firefox the use of which I recommended to her, but even after switching back to Safari, the problems persist. The activity monitor does not show any suspicious items.
I realise that my description is vague and I've found other users complaining about performance issues with Catalina, but as I am not familiar with OS X, I wanted to check if there are common issues that I have not thought of.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try Safe Boot, this loads only necessary files so that might help your Mac check itself for issues. Also you can try the Hardware Diagnostic by rebooting and pressing “D”.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both, the diagnostics found no issue. I disabled bluetooth, maybe this played a part in the problem.

Comment: For future reference: I had another close look at the activity manager and nsurlsessiond took a vast amount of CPU resources. So my problem appeared to be the one described and solved here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251258165